Intellij Idea tries to run gradle on strande java version
I have kotlin project using gradle as build tool. When I build from CLI everything works fine. When I try to run build from idea i get
Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.4 and Gradle 8.2. Cannot sync the project.

We recommend upgrading to Gradle version 8.8.

The minimum compatible Gradle version is 8.5.

The maximum compatible Gradle JVM version is 19.

So I already removed all java from my ubuntu except 17. I removed all jdk from idea:

and platform sdks

I run gradle using 17

I rebooted my laptop
I did repair IDE

I did invalidate caches
I downgraded idea using snap
but nothing helps

I forced java version into build.gradle.kts like this
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

which fixed the problem. I could remove the snippet later and build would work without it. I guess idea or gradle cache everything forever.
